# Android Studio hangs when I press Ctrl + S or I close the project from File menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Android Studio 3.2.1 hangs every time I press Control S (due to my old habit) or I press Close Project from the File Menu.

Studio freezes and if I minimize and maximize the window, studio shows a blank screen for an infinite time.

I am using it on 64bit windows 10 os with 7th generation i5 processor and 8gb ram.

Comment: You can try to reinstall android studio if it takes too much time to solve or is annoying

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It helped:

1. Rename your studio's profile folder, for example, c:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.4 to .AndroidStudio3.4_bak
2. Run Android Studio
3. On the first launch, it will ask about importing settings from .AndroidStudio3.4_bak
4. Choose Yes

You'll get Android Studio with your settings, and clear other temporary data.